# How to create a custom colormap programmatically?

Tags: matlab, color-mapping

I'd like to create a colormap in matlab.
I want to fade the color according to gray level of pixel.

For example:

```
from 255 to 160 -> white 
from 159 to 120 -> pink
from 119 to 50 -> brown
from 49 to 0 -> dark
```

Comment: Try the colormapeditor: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormapeditor.html

Comment: I' d like to do the same thing of colormapeditor but i want to write a matlab funcion. In this case i'm able to change manually the thresholds for the colors according to image i'm using. Sorry for my english!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html):

> A colormap is an m-by-3 matrix of real numbers between 0.0 and 1.0.
>   Each row is an RGB vector that defines one color. The kth row of the
>   colormap defines the kth color, where map(k,:) = [r(k) g(k) b(k)])
>   specifies the intensity of red, green, and blue.

OK so to start we are going to create an m-by-3 matrix, in your case m is 161:

```
m = 161;
map = zeros(m , 3);
```

Now you want the bottom to be dark (I'm going with black) and the 50th point to be brown. but lets go with red as an example as it's easier. RGB triples for black and red respectively: `[0,0,0]` and `[1,0,0]`

OK so currently our enitre colormap is black. We know we want `map(50,:) = [1, 0 ,0]` i.e. red but now we want a gradient in between right? So lets use [linspace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) for this (note that there is a better method using `interp1` instead of `linspace` at the end of this answer):

```
R0to50 = linspace(0,1,50)';
```

putting this in the map:

```
map(1:50, 1) = R0to50;
```

So now lets use [brown](http://colors.findthedata.org/q/609/10857/What-are-the-RGB-values-of-Dark-Brown) instead of red, to get the triple from that link divide each colour component by 255 so our triple is `t = [101, 67, 33]./255`. OK so now just repeat that linspace procedure for each colour:

```
R = linspace(0,t(1),50);
G = linspace(0,t(2),50);
B = linspace(0,t(3),50);

T = [R', G', B'];

map(1:50, :) = T;
```

And now repeat for each of your other nodes.

For example:

```
I = linspace(0,1,161);
imagesc(I(:, ones(10)))
colormap(map)
```

[image]

---

An alternative to using `linspace` once per channel individually and repeating this for each colour is to use linear interpolation.

Create a matrix where each row is a color triple

```
T = [0,   0,   0          %// dark
     101, 67,  33         %// brown
     255, 105, 180        %// pink
     255, 255, 255        %// white
     255, 255, 255]./255; %// white again  -> note that this means values between 161 and 255 will be indistinguishable
```

And now make a vector of what range each color should be at (i.e. this vector defines the spacing of the colours, they need not be regularly/equally spaced):

```
x = [0
     50
     120
     160
     255];
```

And finally you can create the entire map with one simple interpolation:

```
map = interp1(x/255,T,linspace(0,1,255));
```

testing

```
I = linspace(0,1,255);
imagesc(I(ones(1,10),:)')
colormap(map)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much very useful...but another question...if i want to fade the brown color to pink color?

Comment: You should be able to work that out based on the answer above. But instead of `map(1:50...` you'd use `map(51:120...` and instead of `linspace(0,t(1),50)` you'd go `linspace(t(1), t_pink(1), 70)` etc

Comment: I didn't read you reply, but i've done that. It work perfectly!
Thank you very much for your helping

Comment: Creating the map using `interp1` is clever !

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you may use `AdvancedColormap` function from [FEX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41583).
If you need a smooth colormap, you may do it like this:

```
map = AdvancedColormap('kbpw',256,[0 50 120 255]/255);
```