# customize colors in color bar MATLAB

Tags: matlab, colorbar

I have searched a lot but I can not find my answer.I am new to matlab.

I want to show specific colors in color bar based on the values [0 1 2 3 4 5 10 15], in other words I want to reserve colors for these values...for example yellow color between 0 and 1, orange color between 1 and 2, red color between 2 and 3 and so on...I have used code below but It is not the right answer..the main data can be between 0 and 2 , 0 and 10, or 0 and 15..I want to have exactly a specific color for values between 0 and 1 in all of my figures...I have used contourf function. 
here is my code:

```
points = [ 1 1 1 1; 2 2 2 2 ];
> 
> depths = [ 10 5 1 0.5; 10 5 1 0.5];
> 
> RFU27 = [1.46 0.32 0.26 0.26; 1.46 0.32 0.26 0.26];
> 
> contourf(points,depths,RFU27)
> 
> % Design the Plot 
  set(gca, 'XTick', points(1) : points(2),'XTickLabel',{ 'LSB1' , 'LSB2'});
> 
> ylabel('Depth(m)') xlabel('Points') title('Date: 27.08.2013')
> 
> set(get(colorbar('YTickLabel',...
>     {'0','1','2','3',...
>     '4','5','10','15'}),'ylabel'),'String','BGA PC(RFU)');

set(gca,'ydir','rev')
```

and here are some of the real data which I must use in contourf

```
RFU27 = [1.46 0.32 0.26 0.26; 1.46 0.32 0.26 0.26];

RFULast = [2.460869565, 0.539285714, 0.458208955, 0.566666667, 0; 0, 0, 0, 0, 14.27300469];
```

Please Help me, Thanks.

Comment: this earlier thread might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230837/how-to-create-a-custom-colormap-programatically

Comment: have you considered the [colormapeditor](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/colormapeditor.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments to your question by Cici and thewaywewalk are on the right track. To elaborate: `colorbar`, by default, will display a color bar of the current color map, which you can set with the command `colormap`. So once you have set the correct colormap, your color bar should look the way you want it to look (the color bar automatically changes to reflect the current colormap whenever the colormap changes).

You can make a colormap in various ways but it is essentially just a matrix of color values. See the comments in reply to your original question for some ways of doing that...