# To create red-blue-green colormap for medical imaging?

Tags: matlab, color-mapping

I run

```
imagesc(real(lena))
colormap(hsv)
```

where lena is a picture in 512x512 pixels.

I would like to get the special red-green-blue colormap like [here](http://www.ajronline.org/doi/pdf/10.2214/ajr.162.1.8273670) discussed. 
A picture processed by it:

[image]

**How can you get such a colors by the command *colormap*?**

Comment: If there aren't any predefined colour maps that you like, it's pretty easy to make your own: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230837/how-to-create-a-custom-colormap-programatically/17232355#17232355

Comment: @Dan just tried the colormapeditor and was very happy to find such a nice tool. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `colormap bone` to get this gray-ish blue-ish tones for your medical images.
Here's an example of this colormap taken from Mathworks:

[image]

See [manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506174453/https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) for more examples and pre-defined color maps.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the paper describes a way to combine two images, it does not use a color map.

If `a` is the gray-scale normal MRI image, and `b` is the gray-scale contrast-enhanced MRI image, the paper proposes to use `cat(3,a,b,a)` as an RGB image, where contrast-enhancement appears as a green overlay. What that statement does is use the normal image as the red and blue channel, and the contrast-enhanced image as the green channel.