# How to reverse colors of heatmap in Matlab's image()?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

[image: Defult heatmap]

Hi. I am using image() to show my two dimensional matrix as a heatmap, but the problem is that high values are showed in blue colors (cold ones). How to reverse the colors? Thank You for all replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the first hit on Google](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/275433): `colormap(flipud(colormap))`

---

Or else you could just invert the image itself before showing it rather than the colourmap. I'm assuming either your data goes from 0 - 1 or from 0 - 255 so instead of

`imshow(I)` or `imagesc(I)` or ... `image(I)`? you can go `imshow(1 - I)` or `imshow(255 - I)`

---

otherwise you could [create a custom colormap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230837/how-to-create-a-custom-colormap-programatically/17232355#17232355).