# How to calculate MATLAB linspace function by hand

Tags: matlab

There is a function named linspace in matlab and splits interval in given range. For example:

```
>> x = linspace(-10,5, 10)

x =

  -10.0000   -8.3333   -6.6667   -5.0000   -3.3333   -1.6667         0    1.6667    3.3333    5.0000
```

How can I find x(4) by doing calculations by hand ?

Comment: Type `open linspace` and see its code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work -

```
x = linspace(-10,5, 10)

start = -10;
stop = 5;
num_elements = 10;
index = 4;

out = start + (index-1)*(stop - start)./(num_elements-1)
```

Output -

```
x =
  -10.0000   -8.3333   -6.6667   -5.0000   -3.3333   -1.6667    0    1.6667 ...
out =
    -5
```

---

Thus, `(stop - start)./(num_elements-1)` would be the `stepsize`.

So, if you want the complete array, do this -

```
complete_array = start : (stop - start)./(num_elements-1) :stop
```

But, be careful of the floating point precision issues if you are comparing these results against the `linspace` results - [`What is the advantage of linspace over the colon “:” operator?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292695/what-is-the-advantage-of-linspace-over-the-colon-operator).