# Rounding problems when creating date vectors

Tags: arrays, matlab, date, floating-accuracy

I want to create a vector containing dates in matlab. For that I specified the start time and the stop time:

```
WHM01_start = datenum('01-JAN-2005 00:00')
WHM01_stop = datenum('01-SEP-2014 00:00')
```

and then I created the vector with

```
WHM01_timevec = WHM01_start:datenum('01-JAN-2014 00:20') - datenum('01-JAN-2014 00:00'):WHM01_stop;
```

after I want to have time steps of 20 minutes each. Unfortunately I get a rounding error after some thousands of values, leading me to

```
>> datestr(WHM01_timevec(254160))

ans =

31-Aug-2014 23:39:59
```

and not as expected, `31-Aug-2014 23:40:00`
How can I correct these incorrect values?

Edit: I also saw this [thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/7140-produce-a-date-vector-starting-with-a-desired-date), but unfortunately I get there a vector per date, and not a number as desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give year, month, day, ... in numeric format to the function `datenum`. Datenum accepts vectors for one or several of its arguments, and if the numbers are too big (for example, 120 minutes), `datenum` knows what to do with it.

So by supplying the minutes vector in 20-minute increments, you can avoid rounding errors (at least on a 1-second level):

```
WHM01_start = datenum('01-JAN-2005 00:00');
WHM01_stop = datenum('01-SEP-2014 00:00');

time_diff = WHM01_stop - WHM01_start;

WHM01_timevec = test = datenum(2005,01,01,00,[00:20:time_diff*24*60],00);

datestr(WHM01_timevec(254160))
```

To answer your comment:

The reason you saw rounding errors was that you used the difference of two big numbers for your time-increments. The difference of large numbers has a (relatively) large rounding error.

Matlab time is counted in days since the (fictional) date 0.0.0000. Your time-increment is 1/3 hour, or 1/(24*3) days. Modifying your original code so that it reads

```
WHM01_timevec = WHM01_start:1/(24*3):WHM01_stop;
```

is an alternative way to reduce the rounding error, but for absurdely large time spans the first solution is a more robust approach.

Answer (score 4):

[**Related answer:**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26292912/2605073) use [**`linspace`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) instead of the [**colon operator `:`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html).

```
%// given
WHM01_start = datenum('01-JAN-2005 00:00')
WHM01_stop = datenum('01-SEP-2014 00:00')

%// number of elements
n = numel(WHM01_start: datenum('01-JAN-2014 00:20') - ...
                       datenum('01-JAN-2014 00:00') : WHM01_stop);

%// creating vector using linspace
WHM01_timevec = linspace(WHM01_start, WHM01_stop, n);

%// proof
datestr(WHM01_timevec(254160))
```

---

```
ans =

31-Aug-2014 23:40:00
```

Drawback of this solution: to determine the number of elements of the output vector I use the original vector created with `:`, which is not the best option probably.

---

Important quote from the linked answer:

***Using linspace can reduce the probability of occurance of these issue, it's not a security.***