# Matlab - Make an array called bins, with 21 numbers from 0 to 5 (inclusive)

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have to make an array that has 21 numbers from 0-5

They are supposed to be bins for a distribution

I am assuming what is being asked for is an array that has 21 numbers of equally spaced numbers

so the edges are

```
|0 to 0.2381|0.2381 to 0.4762|... and so on
```

How can I do this efficiently in matlab?

I can do this with a for loop, but is there a better way?

Comment: I guess your edges are supposed to be `|0 to 0.25|0.25 to 0.5|` - what you get is for 22 numbers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `linspace` does that for you.

```
>> linspace(0,5,22) % 22 because 0,5 are included
```

You can also use the `:` operator with the desired spacing:

```
>> 0:(5/21):5 % Create an array from 0 to 5 with spacing of 5/21
```

Comment: Your second option is [**not recommend for creating bins**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292695/what-is-the-advantage-of-linspace-over-the-colon-operator/26292912#26292912).