# Custom made colormap for contourf

Tags: matlab, colormap, contourf

I have a 3d function and want to show contours at `[0.683 0.9545 0.9973]`. I want the area `0`->`0.683` to be filled with red, `0.683`->`0.9545` to be blue, `0.9545`->`0.9973` to be green and `0.9973`->`1.0` to be white.

So basically I have the following:

```
contours = [0.0 0.683 0.9545 0.9973 1.0]
contourf(x,y,z,contours)
```

and tried

```
colormap([1 0 0; 0 0 1; 0 1 0; 1 1 1])
```

but it's not right. Please, what should my colormap look like in order to get the colours I want?

Comment: What about it was not right specifically? Perhaps you can upload an image and link to it? Also please add some sample `x`, `y` and `z` data that we can copy and paste straight into Matlab

Comment: In this dropbox file I have x, y, z. Also the plot showing what I get with the default colormap and what I get using the colormap above.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6e1md5qggtnfljv/AAD0bqVhOJlxOIIz_ezIQKkma?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, I would say that you need to have an amount of rows per color proportional to the size of each range. So `0`->`0.683` is a lot bigger than `0.683`->`0.9545`. In your color map you have provided only one row each so Matlab assumes that those colors should be assigned equally over the full range (i.e. `0`->`1`) which with 4 colors means that red is for `0`->`0.25`, blue is for `0.25`->`0.5` etc...

Try something like this answer: [How to create a custom colormap programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230837/how-to-create-a-custom-colormap-programatically/17232355#17232355) but instead of using `linspace`, use `repmat`. You'll need to have enough rows to account for your 4 decimal point precision (which you might want to rethink) so in total you'll have *10 000* rows:

```
red = repmat([1 0 0], 6830, 1);
blue = repmat([0 0 1], 9545 - 6830, 1);
green = repmat([0 1 0], 9973 - 9545, 1);
white = repmat([1 1 1], 10000 - 9973 , 1);

map = [red;blue;green;white];
colormap(map);
```

or alternatively:

```
map = zeros(10000,3);
map(1:6830,1) = 1;
map(6831:9545,3) = 1;
map(9546:9973,2) = 1;
map(9974:end,:) = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Dan! 

I removed the 1.0 contour and it looks exactly like I want it to!

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot upvote you. I don't have enough reputation. But I accepted the answer. Should I do something more?

Comment: No that's all thanks! You can always come back and upvote later if you get enough rep