# Set color of specific values with colormap

Tags: matlab, matrix, colormap

so a small version of what I am trying to accomplish is I have a matrix A;

```
A = [0 1 0; 2 0 0;1 3 6;9 0 1];
imagesc(A)
```

So when I use imagesc(A) I get a nice grid with each value represented by a different color. However I want to be able to set the value of 0 specifically to white and ideally be able to change the other colors as I see fit such as if I know two values represent the same thing like 3 and 6, then they could be set to the same or relatively similar colors. Is imagesc the wrong command to use because from what I can tell it uses a color gradient.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options:

1. you can create your own colormap as shown in [How to create a custom colormap programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230837/how-to-create-a-custom-colormap-programatically/17232355#17232355)
2. or simply map your matrix `A` to a matrix that would be coloured as you want it. So if you know you want `3` and `6` to the same colour then create a mapping function that makes that so. You then use `A` to index the map so the 3rd and 6th element of map must be the same e.g.

   ```
   map = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10];
   imagesc(map(A+1))
   ```

   note that elements 4 and 7 in `map` are the same because your `A` values start from `0`, this is also why there is the `+1` in the second line.

   and then just choose a colormap that starts from white.

Personally I would go with method 1.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I dont know how I didn't find that first one i'm new to this site and programming in general, either way problems solved so thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
% get colormap and set first value to white
cmap = colormap;    
cmap(1,:) = [1 1 1];

% apply new colormap
colormap(cmap);

% display matrix 
imagesc(A);
```

Obviously you can change the colors for other values in the same way