# Colormap - How to set different colours for specific ranges in matlab

Tags: matlab, heatmap, colormap

Now the colorbar is automatically set by the data distribution in the heatmap. I'd like to change the three colours for three specific ranges in the colorbar manually, and re-display the data distribution. 
[0-1500)--blue;
[1500-3000) -- green;
[3000-8000] -- red;
I followed this post: [How to create a custom colormap programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230837/how-to-create-a-custom-colormap-programatically)

but don't know how to apply to my heat map (please see the image below)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIlql.jpg]

Code for generating the image:

```
a =  xlsread('data.xlsx', 'A1:A480'); a = reshape(a,16,30); rgb = colormap([1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1]);
heatmap(a, x, y, '%0.2f', 'Colormap', flipud(rgb), 'NaNColor', [1 1 1], ... 'ShowAllTicks', 45, 'GridLines', ':');
```

So my question is how to re-display the data distribution. For example, I want to put some data that was in the green range [2700-5200] to the new red range [3000-8000].
Could anyone help me on this, please?

Comment: What about some code on how this figure is generated in the first place?

Comment: the original code is very simple, only a column, 480 rows data.