# Painting all bars less lower than a threshold with a single color

Tags: matlab, colors, bar-chart, visualization, matlab-figure

I have a bivariate histogram plot created using [`bar3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar3.html). I'm trying to change the color of the bars that have a height less than a certain threshold, but to no avail. I got this code:

```
h = bar3(dataSample, 0.5);
for n=1:numel(h)
     cdata=get(h(n),'zdata');
     set(h(n),'cdata',cdata,'facecolor','interp')
end
```

[image: Current result]

I can't figure out how to make the plot look like the one below, where the bars less than say 0.001 are gray:

[image: Desired result]

Any ideas?

Comment: just edit the color map that you use...

Comment: Thanks @bla how exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how:

```
z=peaks(20);
h=bar3(z) 
for n=1:numel(h)
 cdata=get(h(n),'zdata');
 set(h(n),'cdata',cdata,'facecolor','interp')
end

colormap([0.5.*ones(128,3); parula(128)]);
```

[image]

I've arbitrarily decided to cut the colormap in the middle, first 128 intensities as gray the next 128 intensities in color. you can cut it however you want. You can find the threshold you want by setting the colormap binning (say to 256 bins) and the place in that partition below which it'll be gray.

Comment: if you want to know more on how to create colormapw programatically see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230837/how-to-create-a-custom-colormap-programatically/17232355#17232355