# How to set up a colormap from white to green with n shades

Tags: matlab

I want to set up a Matlab colormap from white (min values) to green (max values) with any number of shades.
I think about a colormap similiar to the [summer preset](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/summer.html) but reversed and with a white edge instead of the yellow one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a custom colormap programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230837/how-to-create-a-custom-colormap-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

```
c = [zeros(64,1)        linspace(0,1,64)'  zeros(64,1);         % black to green
     linspace(0,1,64)'  ones(64,1)         linspace(0,1,64)'];  % green to white


surf(peaks);
colormap(c);
```

Comment: That produces a colormap from light green to dark green.