# Colormap with different color transition

Tags: matlab, colors, color-scheme, colormap, turbo

I am using the colormap "turbo" in MATLAB. The transition of color is red--orange--yellow--green--light blue--dark blue. Can I create a similar colormap with a different color transition? For example: green--blue--purple--red--orange--yellow. Is there an easy way to do that?

I know that MATLAB uses three-column data format to specify each color, but I don't know how to generate a beautiful color transition by manipulating the digits.

Thank you for any input.

Comment: Check the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230837/how-to-create-a-custom-colormap-programmatically). Adjust the colors for creating your desired custom colormap.

Comment: See the interactive [`colormapeditor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormapeditor.html) tool built into Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `colormapeditor`, that will launch an interactive color map editor.

Once you are satisfied with your colormap, you can get the nColor-by-3 matrix in a variable `cmap` by calling `cmap = colormap`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).